# Can java detect windows 7 notifications

Tags: java

Is it possible for java code to detect when another program notification(the orange flicker on the task bar) appears?

http://community.skype.com/skypec/attachments/skypec/Windows_archive/124867/1/Skype%20Notifcation.jpg

Comment: Seems no. It is as same as cross domain in web :)

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible via standard java API, but it is possible via `JNI`. You have to write your own wrappers under `Windows API` (some own `DLL` for export special API fucntions)  to catch such events.

A little googling gives us several links about this theme:

[Making Windows API calls from JAVA](http://www.atwistedweb.com/java/jni.html)

[Making Native Windows API calls from within a Java Application](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/20679)